# Constrain GAN so the subject is always the same

Tags: gan

I want to build a face GAN, but I want to be able to control the 'camera angle' of the generated image, and I also want the subject (the generated face) to be the same every time.

If the above is possible, then it seems like it could generate the variety of angles necessary for something like photogrammetry.

Is this possible? How would I implement the constraints?